# Simple Image Inpainting

Tags: image-processing

I'm new to this so forgive me if my question sounds silly.
I'm trying to fill a certain hole in an image based on the pixel around the hole.
Semantics are not our concerns here so I'm just looking for a simple method or algorithm to do so.
For example, if we have this picture below, I need the area in the hole to have a similar color to the one surrounding it.

[image: sample image]

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know how to detect holes in your image, you can use simple interpolation to fill it. Since you don't ask specifically about the programming environment you want to use, you can read this article

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/interpolation.html

It is MATLAB, probably the simplest language that will allow you to accomplish your task. Hope it will help.